# remove duplicate from a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, unique, stdvector

I have a vector of custom objects and am required to sort it under various criteria(i.e. cannot use set). I also have a comparator to do the sorting, which forces me to use a vector of pointers. This way, the code compiles but it is now failing to remove duplicates.

```
vector<customObj*> vec;

//code to remove duplicate
vector<customObj*>::iterator it;
it = unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.resize(distance(vec.begin(), it));

//code to sort a vector
bool Comp(customObj *a, customObj *b) {
    if (condition) {
        return (a->getValue() < b->getX=Value());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demostrates the symptoms of the failure and describe them.

Comment: The expression `b->getX=Value()` looks weird embedded into the condition, is this really what you wanted? At least surround it with braces, but better yet - do it on a separate line before `return`.

Comment: why "cannot use set" ? You can use one set to construct a different set with different comparator. Not sure if it is ok with complexity, but its not "cannot". A single vector is also sorted only with repsect to one comparator

Comment: Your comparator returns nothing if "condition" is false .. Is that intentional or just left out when copy-pasting? Your compiler should be yelling at you.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, so think about this mathematical identity: "¬(a < b) && ¬(b > a) <=> (a == b)". Also note that `std::unique` can accept an optional equality function.

Comment: There are particular requirements that a comparator must satisfy, otherwise `std::sort()` has undefined behaviour.   On the face of it, your comparator is pretty suspicious - it returns without a `return` statement if `condition` is `false` (causing undefined behaviour) and it is not clear that it defines a strict-weak ordering (which is another requirement to avoid undefined behaviour in `std::sort()`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a typo in the comparison function

```
//code to sort a vector
bool Comp(customObj *a, customObj *b) {
    if (condition) {
        return (a->getValue() < b->getX=Value());
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Also the comparison function returns nothing if the condition does not evaluate to true.

I think you mean

```
//code to sort a vector
bool Comp(customObj *a, customObj *b) {
        return condition && (a->getValue() < b->getValue());
}
```

In the call of std::unique you need to use a binary predicate like

```
//code to sort a vector
bool Equal(customObj *a, customObj *b) {
        return consdition && (a->getValue() == b->getValue());
}

vector<customObj*>::iterator it;
it = unique(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Equal);
vec.resize(distance(vec.begin(), it));
```

Pay attention to that if objects in the vector were dynamically allocated then you need to free them. Otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Instead of raw pointers you should use smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: what does it return when `condition == false` ?